# Creating a thread in signal handlers

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

In my program I need to perform some action upon timer (timer_create()) expiration. I want to perform this action by spawning a new thread. So I want to know if it is safe to create a thread in signal handlers?

Comment: Call `timer_create()` with a `struct sigevent` with `.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD`.

Answer (score 2):

Signal handlers may not call non re-entrant functions. You should look at your o/s documentation but creating a thread is unlikely to be re-entrant. On linux, `man -s7 signal` gives you a list of safe to call functions, which doesn't include anything from pthread.

Really all a signal handler should do is to set a flag for the main code or a signal handling thread to read. More than that gets risky.